# Field Audit Trail not populating changes

Tags: history-tracking, field-history, lightning-record-page, field-audit-trail

I have added the field audit trail component to a lightning page and enabled history tracking on the object and relevant field, however field history isn't showing up on the related tab (the grid shows, but a field change that was made isn't appearing).    Is there another configuration setting that I could be missing?

Answer (score 0):

Run the following query (this is an example for ContactHistory). If you did get the results, you might not have added Object History and instead added Activity History-related list. Also there are various limitations on what fields show up and what don't https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.tracking_field_history.htm&type=5

```
SELECT ContactId, DataType, Field, NewValue, OldValue, CreatedById, CreatedDate
FROM ContactHistory
ORDER BY CreatedDate ASC
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: I've never run a query, how do I do that?

Comment: Am I supposed to add a related list on the lightning record page or via the standard layout?

Comment: Yes. That's how you can see history. Every object has History object. You go to the page layout --> related lists --> find your objectHistory related list and drop into your page layout. Make sure you don't use Activity History

Comment: Awesome thank you!  I'm new to this forum, is there any way to mark an answer as "best answer" similar to Trailhead?

Comment: I'm relatively new on this forum as well. I think depending on our reputation score, we see various options like selecting the best answer or upvoting. I'm glad I was able to help